# Google CSE PHP CURL Implementation to programmatically add/delete annotations

Tags: php, curl

I have been working with Googgle's Custom Search Engine API to programmatically add and delete annotations. I feel like I have followed their documentation and others tips very closely. I can't seem avoiding a 'bad request' HTTP 400 error. My code is below

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/cse/api/default/annotations/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);    


curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array(
    "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='DQAAAMI......n9dGUyA'",
    "Content-Type: text/xml"
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'.chr(10);
$data .= '<Batch>'.chr(10);
$data .= chr(9).'<Add>'.chr(10);
$data .= chr(9). chr(9).'<Annotations>'.chr(10);
$data .= chr(9). chr(9). chr(9).'<Annotation about=\"\">'.chr(10);
$data .= chr(9).chr(9). chr(9). chr(9).'<Label name=\"my_engine\"/>'.chr(10);
$data .= chr(9). chr(9). chr(9).'</Annotation>'.chr(10);
$data .= chr(9). chr(9).'</Annotations>'.chr(10);
$data .= chr(9).'</Add>'.chr(10);
$data .= '</Batch>'.chr(10);    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

$result = curl_exec($ch);

```
if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
        $result = 'cURL ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo  $returnCode."<br/>";
    switch($returnCode){
        case 200:
            break;
        default:
            $result = 'HTTP ERROR -> ' . $returnCode;
            break;
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

if anybody can help me or at least steer me in the right direction I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

Ok, firstly, you'll need to encode the xml data thats sent to google.  Secondly you should get rid of all the tabs and formatting, the receiving engine is not concerned with that.

So try this:

```
$data = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Batch><Add><Annotations><Annotation about=\"\"><Label name=\"my_engine\"/></Annotation></Annotations></Add></Batch>';     
$data = urlencode($data);  // encode the string to send via http
```

I think that should get you going.  You may find other errors but this should clear the 400 error you are getting.